# Unable to load data into the table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

In my app.i have some classes and inside one class I am calling method in other class. In my other class I have a table view and an array "data". When the query is executed in this method then I am adding the data obtained from the execution of the query to the array and then I am calling reload data for the table view. But to my surprise table view is not getting reloaded and I am not getting any sort of data on the table view. It is showing just a blank table view.

The method which is called from other class:

```
-(void)searchImagesInCategory:(NSString *)string
{
    data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    string1=string;    
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory= [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Table.sqlite"];

    //Open the database
    //might have to make database as property

    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &dataBase) ==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        NSString *strSQL = [[NSString alloc]init];
        strSQL = @"select ImageName from tblLanguageElement where Category='";
        strSQL = [[strSQL stringByAppendingString:string1] stringByAppendingString:@"'"];

        const char *bar = [strSQL UTF8String]; 
        //strSQL = [strSQL stringByAppendingString:"''"];
        //NSLog(strSQL);
        if(sqlite3_prepare(dataBase, bar, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]);
                [data addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
            }

            tableView1.delegate=self;
            tableView1.dataSource=self;
        }

    }
    [tableView1 reloadData];
}
```

My cell for row at index path method:-

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.imageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;        
}
```

Why i am not getting the reloaded Table view.Please help.

Thanks,

Christy

Comment: Does anything show up in the console i.e. do you get results from the query?

Comment: yes i get the result from the querry and also the data array shows 4 object in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method you are re-initializing your "data" array. Try making this a local variable by declaring it in your header file and then in your viewDidLoad method call:

```
     data= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Also there is no need to reset the delegate and data source. Just do it once and leave it.

This is an edit from something else I have seen. You need to bind your variable and not just append the string. Here is an example....

```
- (NSMutableArray*) getAllImagesForCategory:(NSString*)category {
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];;

   const char *sqlStatement = "select ImageName from tblLanguageElement where Category=?";
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement,1,category); //this is where you put your variable into the statement

    while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        // Read the data from the result row

        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];


        [tempArray addObject:imageName];

    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: Failed to select all images with message '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

   // Release the compiled statement from memory
   sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
   return tempArray;
}
```

So this is the SQL statement that will get the stuff from the database. To call this method you go something like this.

```
_data = [self getAllImagesForCategory];
[tableView1 reloadData];
```

I hope this helps any questions just ask.

Comment: but i am getting the querry result

Comment: Check the answer again. I have added

Comment: What is the problem with my code ,,,i think both are specifying the same purpose

Comment: and also i declared the array in header as you said but still inside the method after adding the object the count of the array is still 0

Comment: I guess you are opening your database? The problem with the way you are specifying the variable. With SQL statements you need to bind the variable to the statement.

Comment: Did this help then? Manage to do what yo were trying to?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are returning the correct number in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: returning the count of my array

Comment: Try adding a break point to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Does it get triggered?

Comment: no it is not getting triggered ,,i tried using break point what might be the reason for that?

Comment: In your `searchImagesInCategory:` method you're referencing a `tableView1`variable. Did you remember to set it to an instance of a table view?

Comment: tableView1 is the name of the table view present in my view.What i have to do now with it please tell i am  afresher in this thats y asking so much?

Comment: There could be so many reasons why it doesn't work. If your view controller is created with Interface Builder, did you remember to connect all the outlets? If the view controller is created in code, has the table view been added to the view stack? Is the tableView1 variable assigned to the table view you're trying to reload? Does any of the table view data source and delegate messages get called (if you're not familiar with break points, then add log statements to verify that they're called)?

Comment: i added breakpoits to the methods and i am sure they are not called

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure that your tableView1 variable is either not set, or is pointing to a table view that is not being shown. If you break in `searchImagesInCategory:` at the line `tableView1.delegate=self;` you can see if the tableView1 variable is nil. If it's not nil, then you need to add the table view it's pointing to to the view hierarchy.

Comment: i checked that also it is shwoing null

Comment: Did you load your view controller with the table view from a nib or did you create it in code?

Comment: Did you remember to connect the table view to a variable in the controller? Try right clicking on the table view in Interface Builder, and see if it has any connection to a variable.